# User Defined TCP Port Permissions

Tags: ubuntu, networking, permissions, users, tcp

Is there a way in Ubuntu to set TCP ports permissions for individual users?

For example, userA is only allowed to open ports between 3000-3010. So if userA ran the following `php -S 0.0.0.0:3001`, it would work. But if they try running `php -S 0.0.0.0:3200`, they will get a permission denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without involving MAC(SELinux or AppArmor), you could do this quick'n dirty hack with iptables:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -o ethX -m owner --uid-owner <userA_UID> -m multiport --dports 3000-3010 -j ACCEPT
```

However, it will log nothing to the user, and will still allow the user to [bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) the port. He will just suffer from symptoms of having a port blocked